# Send the reset password email notifications programatically in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I would like to send the reset password email to the automatically registered guests after their first order on my woocommerce website.

Here is my hooked function:

```
function wc_register_guests($order_id) {
    // get all the order data
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

    //get the user email from the order
    $order_email = $order->billing_email;

    // check if there are any users with the billing email as user or email
    $email = email_exists($order_email);
    $user = username_exists($order_email);

    // if the UID is null, then it's a guest checkout
    if ($user == false && $email == false) {

        $random_password = wp_generate_password();

        // create new user with email as username & newly created pw
        $user_id = wp_create_user($order_email, $random_password, $order_email);

        //WC guest customer identification
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'guest', 'yes');

        //user's billing data
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_address_1', $order->billing_address_1);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_address_2', $order->billing_address_2);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_city', $order->billing_city);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_company', $order->billing_company);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_country', $order->billing_country);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_email', $order->billing_email);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_first_name', $order->billing_first_name);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_last_name', $order->billing_last_name);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_phone', $order->billing_phone);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_postcode', $order->billing_postcode);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_state', $order->billing_state);

        // user's shipping data
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_address_1', $order->shipping_address_1);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_address_2', $order->shipping_address_2);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_city', $order->shipping_city);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_company', $order->shipping_company);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_country', $order->shipping_country);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_first_name', $order->shipping_first_name);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_last_name', $order->shipping_last_name);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_method', $order->shipping_method);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_postcode', $order->shipping_postcode);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_state', $order->shipping_state);

        wc_update_new_customer_past_orders($user_id);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'wc_register_guests', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To send the Customer reset password email-notification you will use from a user ID:

```
$user = new WP_User( intval($user_id) );
$reset_key = get_password_reset_key( $user );
$wc_emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();
$wc_emails['WC_Email_Customer_Reset_Password']->trigger( $user->user_login, $reset_key );
```

See [this related source code function](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Email_Customer_Reset_Password.html#66-88).

---

Now since Woocommerce 3+ you can't get anymore the `WC_Order` properties directly and instead you should use the [`WC_Order` available methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html)… 
Also you should set the "customer" user role…

So I have revisited your code a bit:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'wc_register_new_customers', 10, 1);
function wc_register_new_customers( $order_id ) {
    if(is_user_logged_in()) return; // Only for unlogged users

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Get the customer billing email from the order
    $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();

    // check if there are any users with the billing email as user or email
    $email = email_exists( $billing_email );
    $user = username_exists( $billing_email );

    // if the UID is null, then it's a guest checkout
    if ( $user == false && $email == false ) {

        $random_password = wp_generate_password();

        // Create new user with email as username & newly created pw
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $billing_email, $random_password, $billing_email );

        // WC guest customer identification
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'guest', 'yes' );

        //user's billing data
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', $order->get_billing_address_1() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_2', $order->get_billing_address_2() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', $order->get_billing_city() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_company', $order->get_billing_company() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', $order->get_billing_country() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $order->get_billing_email() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $order->get_billing_first_name() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', $order->get_billing_last_name() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $order->get_billing_phone() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', $order->get_billing_postcode() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_state', $order->get_billing_state() );

        // user's shipping data
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_1', $order->get_shipping_address_1() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_2', $order->get_shipping_address_2() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_city', $order->get_shipping_city() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_company', $order->get_shipping_company() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_country', $order->get_shipping_country() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_first_name', $order->get_shipping_first_name() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_last_name', $order->get_shipping_last_name() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_method', $order->get_shipping_method() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_postcode', $order->get_shipping_postcode() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_state', $order->get_shipping_state() );

        // Update to "customer" user role
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_capabilities', array('customer' => true) );

        wc_update_new_customer_past_orders( $user_id );

        // Get WP_User
        $user = new WP_User( intval( $user_id ) );

        // Creates, stores, then returns a password reset key for user.
        $reset_key = get_password_reset_key( $user );

        // Send the WC_email Customer Reset Password
        $wc_emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();
        $wc_emails['WC_Email_Customer_Reset_Password']->trigger( $user->user_login, $reset_key );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works.

Comment: Yes the user role is set :) but i haven't received the reset password email-notification.You have any idea why? Thanks

Comment: i have updated the code but i haven't received the email! everything seems to be right but the email notification wasn't triggered. i really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Ok :). FYI I have replaced the variable $order_email by $billing_email on this line $user_id = wp_create_user( $order_email, $random_password, $order_email );

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the result is the same